# How config Stylelint in vue3 app(vscode) to lint on save

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, stylelint

I want to lint my scss files and scss scope in .vue components. my config in stylelint.config:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'stylelint-config-standard',
    'stylelint-config-recess-order',
    'stylelint-config-prettier',
    'stylelint-config-css-modules',
  ],
  plugins: [
    'stylelint-scss',
  ],
  rules: {},
}
```

and package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint:all:stylelint": "yarn lint:stylelint \"src/**/*.{vue,scss}\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "stylelint": "^14.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.3",
    "stylelint-config-recess-order": "^3.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^24.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^4.0.0",
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work. any solution?

Answer (score 5):

[You need to specify](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started/#linting-everything-else) a custom syntax using the [`customSyntax` option](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/usage/options/#customsyntax) when linting anything other than CSS with Stylelint.

However, rather than use the `customSyntax` option yourself, you can extend shared configs that do it for you:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'stylelint-config-standard-scss', // configure for SCSS
    'stylelint-config-recommended-vue', // add overrides for .Vue files
    'stylelint-config-recess-order', // use the recess order for properties
    'stylelint-config-css-modules', // configure for CSS Modules methodology
    'stylelint-config-prettier' // turn off any rules that conflict with Prettier
  ]
}
```

The `stylelint-config-standard-scss` and `stylelint-config-recommended-vue` shared configs will configure Stylelint for SCSS and Vue files, respectively.

You don't need to include the `stylelint-scss` plugin yourself either, as that also comes in `stylelint-config-standard-scss`.